# php is not changing header to application/json ( data sent from python to get json response)

Tags: python, php, json

Hi I have this php code:

```
<?php
$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["firstname"]);
$lastname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["lastname"]);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_GET["password"]);
$result['username']=$firstname;
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($result); 
exit ;
?>
```

And this python code:

```
import requests
def send(firstname,lastname,password):
    userdata = {"firstname": firstname, "lastname":lastname , "password": password}
    resp = requests.post('http://www.example.com/php.php', params=userdata)
    print ( 'Content-Type:'  )
    print( resp.headers['Content-Type'])
    getdata = resp.json()
    print (getdata[ 'username'  ]  )

send('yama','last','password')
```

My python output is:

```
Content-Type:
text/html

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 35, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 32, in send
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

So you can see in my output that Content-Type:
text/html and it is not application/json, What should I do?
I know this question is dublicated but I tryed everything on stackoverflow answers and my codes still not working for me!

Comment: Your Python code is sending a POST request, not a GET request (which your PHP code assumes)

Comment: I have tryed GET and still have the same result output :/

Comment: If you look at the raw response body (before/without using `resp.json()`), you will most likely see "undefined index/array key". That will cause the `header()` call to fail (since headers will already have been sent), and will also make your `respo.json()` fail in Python (since the response will include warning/error messages, which won't be valid JSON). You say that you've tried it with GET, did you send the data in the correct way in the URL then? Have you tried keeping it as POST but simply done `$_POST['firstname']` etc?

Comment: Looking at the [docs for requests in Python](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) (if it's this you're using), it seems like it also should be `params=userdata` for GET requests, but `data=userdata` for POST requests? I'm no Python developer, but it seems like you're mixing request methods, how you send the data and then how you're trying to fetch the data in PHP.

Comment: I think the problem is in php code because if I change my url to api.github.com insisted of my website url the output result is :Content-Type:
application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: That didn't actually address or answer _anything_ I mentioned in my comments (which addresses multiple issues, both in PHP and Python). What github returns is completely irrelevant here. Do a `resp.text()` _and see what the response actually is_. Use the `data` keyword to send data in a POST request in your Python code. Get POST data in PHP using `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`. We have _no idea_ what your GET attempt looks like so just saying that you've "tried that" tells us _nothing_ (we can't assume you made that correctly either). Also, you should check PHP's error log for clues as well.

Comment: I have changed my python code `resp = requests.post('http://www.example.com/php.php', params=userdata)` to `resp = requests.post('http://www.example.com/php.php', data=userdata)`  and add ;`print (resp.text)`.  php code `$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_GET["firstname"]);` to  `$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstname"]);`

Comment: outputs part1: `Content-Type:
text/html
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("04ebe7df6cf2053e2e31df4e84b39dfc");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decryp`

Comment: output patr2: `slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://example.com/php.php?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>`

Comment: There is a phrase in output said : **This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support** so it's looks like a Javascript support problem ?

Comment: That response isn't outputted/caused by the posted PHP code. Make sure the URL you're posting to is actually correct.

Comment: it is actually correct you can check it [link](http://popo.infinityfreeapp.com/?i=1)

Comment: I have no idea what hosting that is, but that response is a server/hosting issue, not a code issue. If you access that URL in a browser, you see the JSON. If you send a POST request to it, depending on what headers you send to it, it can return a 400 bad request response or the HTML/JS you posted in the comments. When you're using any "free" hosting, you get what you pay for. This isn't a code problem...

Comment: I use this hosting for learn and test purpose , So if I move to payed hosting it must work?

Comment: I can't answer anything about that hosting... free or paid. All I can say that the URL works for GET requests in a browser, but not for POST requests (tried using Postman) which can return different types of responses (none based on your PHP code) depending on what headers you send with the POST request. You need to take it up with the hosting provider. Why not run the code locally on your computer while testing/learning instead? There are many easy to install dev environments if you do some research.